# Prove that a Cauchy sequence of piecewise functions does not converge unde the $L_1$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that the following sequence of functions does not converge and this will prove that the space of continous functions $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_1)$ is not complete, so the sequence is:

$$\displaystyle f_{n_{1}}(x) = \begin{cases}\sqrt n & 0\le x<\dfrac{1}{n}\\\dfrac{1}{\sqrt x} & \dfrac{1}{n}\le x\le 1.\end{cases}$$

I have already prove that it is Cauchy, but How can I prove that it does not converge?, the same problem happens with the following function:

$$\displaystyle f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x\geq1/2\\0 & x\le\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{n} & \\ 
n(x-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{n}) &\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{n} \leq x \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

I don't know how can I prove that this Cauchy under the $L^{2}$ norm and is not convergent this is to prove that $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_2)$ is not complete

Can you help me with this please (both functions)?

NOTE: I can't use that $\{f_{n_{1}}\}$ converges to $1/ \sqrt(x)$
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Ian That does go to zero.

Comment: Can someone tell me which comment is correct please :)

Comment: zhw is right, the $1/n$ part is $O(n^{-1/2})$. I didn't look carefully enough.

Comment: Ok no problem :) I'll wait :)

Comment: A better idea: if a sequence converges in $L^1$, then its limit is unique up to a.e. equivalence. Your sequence *does* converge in $L^1$, to (the equivalence class of) $x^{-1/2}$. If this class has a continuous representative, then it must be in $L^\infty$...but that's impossible.

Comment: I used that but my proffesor told me that if I say that the functions $f_n$ converge to $1/x^{1/2}$ then I'm not proving nothing because is like to prove that a sequence of reals doesn't converge to $n$ (an arbitrary number)

Comment: This is a subtle matter, which is why I used explicit equivalence classes in my description. The point is that any $L^1$ limit must be equal a.e. to $x^{-1/2}$, and none of these are in $C([0,1])$, since $C([0,1]) \subset L^\infty$. You're right that it's not enough to prove that the sequence doesn't converge to some *particular* limit to prove that it doesn't converge to *any* limit, but what I said does prove that it doesn't converge to any (continuous) limit.

Comment: Being formal, you could write it by contradiction: suppose you have a continuous limit, then it is equal to $x^{-1/2}$ a.e., but now you have a continuous, unbounded function on a compact set; contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for this but the part where I am stuck is how to argue, "then it is equal to $x/\sqrt(x)$" using basic analysis that is what I have only :)

Comment: Well...you can prove the limit is $x^{-1/2}$ by monotone convergence or dominated convergence. The fact that $L^1$ limits are unique up to a.e. equivalence is one of the basic properties of $L^1$ (without it, $L^1$ wouldn't be a metric space but rather a pseudometric space).

Answer (score 4):

For the first problem: Suppose $f_n \to f\in C([0,1])$ in this norm. Suppose $f(x_0)\ne 1/\sqrt x_0$ for some $x_0\in (0,1).$ Because $f$ is continuous at $x_0,$ we have $f \ne 1/\sqrt x$ in some interval $[x_0,b],$ where $x_0<b<1.$ Thus

$$\tag 1 \int_{x_0}^b|1/\sqrt x - f(x)|\,dx > 0.$$

Now if $n > 1/x_0,$ then $f_n(x) = 1/\sqrt x, x\ge x_0.$ Thus $\|f_n-f\|_1$ is at least as large as $(1)$ for all such $n.$ That's a contradiction. We conclude $f(x) = 1/\sqrt x$ on $(0,1).$ Therefore $f$ is unbounded, hence $f\not \in C([0,1],$ contradiction.

---

Second problem sketch: To show $f_n$ is Cauchy, note that if $m<n,$ then

$$\int_0^1|f_n-f_m|^2 = \int_{1/2-1/m}^{1/2}|f_n-f_m|^2 \le 1\cdot(1/m).$$

Suppose $f_n \to f\in C([0,1])$ in this norm. An idea close to that for the first problem shows $f= 0$ on $[0,1/2), f=1$ on $[1/2,1],$ contradiction.

Comment: why the limits of the integrals are different from 0 and 1?

Comment: Because no $f_n(x) = 1/\sqrt x$ on the entire interval. However in a small interval containing $x_0$  $f_n(x) = 1/\sqrt x$ for all sufficiently large $n.$

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, another way to see this is considering the sequence $\{f_n(0)\}$, this is unbounded as n goes to infinity so it cant converge :) am I right?

Comment: No, because $f_n \to f$ in this norm is possible even though $f_n(0) \to \infty.$ For example $\sqrt n (1-x)^n \to 0$ in this norm.

Comment: Ok, right :) so I better put your answer :), And for the other one ?

Comment: i added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you explain in the first sequence where is the contradiction please?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the second sequence is $L^2$-Cauchy by a direct calculation, as $$||f_n-f_{n+1}||^2_2= \int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}f_n(x)^2 dx+ \int_{a_{n+1}}^{1/2}(f_n(x)-f_{n+1}(x))^2 dx = O(n^{-3})$$   where $$a_n=1/2-1/n$$  .  So $$||f_n-f_{n+1}||_2 =  O({n^{-3/2}})$$ which suffices....................... For the first sequence, if $g \in C[0,1]$ then $g(x) \ne 1/ \sqrt x$ for some $x \in (0,1]$  otherwise $g$ is discontinuous at zero .Now the continuity of $g$ implies that, for some $k>0$  and some $y \in (0,x)$, we have $|g(z)-1/ \sqrt z | >k$ for all  $z \in [y,x]$. This implies $$||g-f_n||_1 > k(x-y)$$ for all but finitely many $n$, so $g$ cannot be the  $L^ 1$ limit of $(f_n)_{n \in N}$.................... You may use this method for the second sequence :   If $g \in C[0,1]$ there exists $x \in [0,1/2)$ with $g(x) \ne 0 $,or some $x \in (1/2,1]$ with $g(x) \ne 1$   Now show that $g$ cannot be the $L^2$ limit of $(f_n)_{n \in N}$

Comment: Ok but Can you help me if I am stuck please because now time is not my friend :)

Comment: As in the first problem,  if  $g$ is continuous then there exists  either some $x  \in (0,1/2) $ with $|g(x)|>j $ or some $x \in (1/2,1)$  with  $ |1-g(x)|>j$ ,for some $ j>)0$. In the first case ,there exists $e>0$ such that $(x-e,x+e) \subset  (0,1/2)$  such that, for some $ k \in (0,j) $, we have $|g(y)|> k $ for all $ y \in (x-e,x+e)$ .But there are only finitely many $ n $ for which $ f_n(y)$  is not identically $ 0$  on $(x-e,x+e)$ , So $2ek^2 \le  ||f_n-g||^2_2$  for all but finitely many $n$ The case  $x \in (1/2)$  is handled almost identically.